# Breaking product of three vectors into symmetric and anti-symmetric vectors

Tags: symmetry, vectors, tensor-calculus, linear-algebra, matrix-elements

Let's consider we have three arbitrary vectors A, B and C. We have the quantity $A_{\mu}B_{\nu}C_{\rho}$. Is it possible to break the above quantity into sum of symmetric and anti-symmetric vectors in any two indices?

Comment: Do you mean symmetric and anti-symmetric *tensors*?  Talking about "symmetric and anti-symmetric vectors" isn't really standard terminology and I'm not sure what you mean by it.

Comment: No. What I meant is symmetric in any two indices, say $\mu$ and $\nu$ of the tensor $A_{\mu}B_{\nu}C_{\rho}$.

Comment: For 3 objects there will be pieces with mixed symmetry in general so not it is not strictly possible to break this into symmetric and antisymmetric, much less with 2 indices.

Comment: Are you trying to extend what is done with rank-2 tensors, which can be split into purely (anti)symmetric parts?

Comment: @JEB yes! thats exactly what I am seeking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generalization of the well known rank 2 formula:

$$ S^{\pm}_{ij} = \frac 1 2 (T_{ij} \pm T_{ji} )$$

to higher ranks is involved. One reason this decomposition is popular is because the R.H.S represents sub-spaces that are closed under rotations: the 3 independent components of $S^-_{ij}$ rotate like the vector:
$ v_i = \frac 1 2 \epsilon_{ijk}S^-_{jk} $, and the rotated tensor is still antisymmetric. Meanwhile, $S^+_{ij}$ remains symmetric under rotations.

It's pretty simple because there are only 2 permutations on 2 indices.

The relationship, for Euclidean tensor in 3 dimensions is written:

$${\bf 3} \otimes {\bf 3} = {\bf 6}_S \oplus {\bf 3}_A $$

which is read as the tensor product of two 3-dimensional representations (read: vectors) can be expressed as the tensor sum of a 6-dimensional irreducible representation (irrep) and 3-dimensional irrep. (Irreducible means: closed under rotations, in this context). The subscripts $S, A, M$ refer to "symmetric", "antisymmetric" and "mixed" symmetries under index permutations.

The numbers are computed from the remarkable hook-length formula (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hook_length_formula), which works for a tensor and spinor ranks, so the same formula applies to electron spins gives:

$${\bf 2} \otimes {\bf 2} = {\bf 3}_S \oplus {\bf 1}_A $$

The R.H.S. is the well-known triplet and singlet states of 2 electron spins.

Meanwhile, in relativity, where 4-vectors are the fundamental 4-dimensional representation:

$${\bf 4} \otimes {\bf 4} = {\bf 10}_S \oplus {\bf 6}_A $$

Note that the metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ has 10 components, while electromagnetism  's $F_{\mu\nu}$ has 6 components.

For rank 3, you have to consider all permutations on 3 indices. For Cartesian tensors:

$${\bf 3} \otimes {\bf 3} \otimes {\bf 3}  = 
{\bf 10}_S \oplus {\bf 8}_M \oplus {\bf 8}_M \oplus {\bf 1}_A $$

The symmetric combination is just the sum over all permutations:

$$ S_{ijk} = \frac 1 6(
T_{ijk} + T_{kij} + T_{jki} + T_{kij}+T_{jik}+T_{jik}
)$$

which has 10 independent components, and the antisymmetric combination:

$$ A_{ijk} = \frac 1 6(
T_{ijk} + T_{kij} + T_{jki} - T_{kij}-T_{jik}-T_{jik}
)$$

has 1, and so is proportional to $\epsilon_{ijk}$.

The mixed combinations are:

$$ M^{(1)}_{ijk} = \frac 1 3(
T_{ijk} + T_{jik} - T_{kji}-T_{kij}
)$$

and

$$ M^{(2)}_{ijk} = \frac 1 3(
T_{ijk} + T_{jik} - T_{kji}-T_{jik}-T_{kij}
)$$

each if which are symmetric on 1 pair of indices, and antisymmetric on another, hence the name: "mixed".

For 3 electron spins, you get:

$${\bf 2} \otimes {\bf 2} \otimes {\bf 2}  = 
{\bf 4}_S \oplus {\bf 2}_M \oplus {\bf 2}_M \oplus {\bf 0}_A $$

${\bf 4}_S$ refers to the spin $\frac 3 2$ combination; then there are two spin $\frac 1 2$ combinations. ${\bf 0}_A$ means there are no totally antisymmetric combinations of 3 electron spins, a fact that important for atomic physics.

If you start subtracting traces, you get a further decomposition, e.g. a rank-2 symmetric tensor has an invariant trace that transforms like a scalar ($\bf 1$):

$$ {\bf 6}_S \rightarrow {\bf 5} \oplus {\bf 1}$$

The ${\bf 5}$ refers to a symmetric, traceless, rank-2 tensor, which is called a "natural-form rank-2 tensor". Note that $5=2l+1$ for $l=2$, and the components rotate just like the spherical harmonics $Y_{l=2}^m(\theta, \phi)$.

Such decompositions are possible for all the irreps, e.g.:

$$ {\bf 8}_M \rightarrow {\bf 5} \oplus {\bf 3}$$

(a natural form rank-2 part and a vector part).

For the rank-3 symmetric part, you get:

$$ {\bf 10}_S \rightarrow {\bf 7} \oplus {\bf 3}$$

Note $7 = 2(l+1)$ for $l=3$ for the traceless symmetric rank-3 tensor, while the ${\bf 3}$ is proportional trace on any 2 indices ($S_{iij} = S_{iji} = S_{jii})$ and rotates like a vector.

At rank-4 it's a multi-page mess (https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.25.2647), but has application in anisotropic elastic media (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1208.1041.pdf).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Got what I was looking for.

Comment: @UtsabDey You're welcome. The two mathematical theories behind this are Schur-Weyl duality and the Robinson–Schensted correspondence, but I find presentations of those too abstract sometimes.